# Associated C*-Categories and the reduced crossed product

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be a discrete group and $\mathcal{G}$ a groupoid, that is a small category in which every arrow is an isomorphism. Wolfgang Lück explains how we can construct a $C^*$-category from $\mathcal{G}$ [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35jIW.png). This construction is very useful because if we consider a discrete group $G$ as a groupid with one element $e$ and morphisms  $Mor_G(e,e)=G$, then $Mor_{C_r(G)}(e,e)$ agrees with the reduced group $C^*$ -algebra $C_r(G)$, as the notation implies.
Now, I want to find a way to extend this principle to the reduced crossed product:

Let $A$ be a $G$-$C^*$-algebra. I want to find a to construct a simililar functor $F$ as described by Lück, only that if I consider $G$ or a subgroup $H$ of $G$ to be a groupoid, I actually have $Mor_{F(H)}(e,e)$ agree with the reduced cross product of $H$ and $A$.

My only idea so far is basically to exchange $\mathbb{C}$ for $A$, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you